# javascript code for embeding link with its details like in facebook

Tags: javascript

i want a javascript code which would fetch page contents like thumbnail images and  contents and some text from the body as is shown in facebook when a link is shared .
please suggest me some technique or code for doing so

Comment: Too broad a question. Narrow it down to something more specific. We're not going to write an entire module for you.

Comment: @Marc B actually i am unable to load sites content..I tried with child iframes and also with jquery load and get..please suggest some function or technique to load a page ... i can do the rest part ....only a javascript function to load the given links page is needed for example load google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) would probably work for your purposes

Comment: no load is not working i have tried  If you feel that it would work please post a code loading any sites page content ...

Comment: If you posted your code, one could easily figure out why it wasn't working, because there is no good reason as to why it isn't an appropriate solution to this task.